# Number theory problem (part of)

Tags: number-theory

Any examples of a cubic residue mod 19?

I'm in the middle of making a list to find some. Are there any examples that you happen to know of? Any examples would be helpful. Thanks!

edit: I meant non-trivial cubic residues (i.e not the direct cube of something)

Answer (score 2):

All the cubic residues can be obtain by cubing residue classes $\bmod 19$. Since you asked for an example $2^3=8$ is a cubic residue $\bmod 19$

The number of quadratic residues $\bmod 19$ is $7$ because the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_{19}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{18}$. So there are $6$ quadratic residues other than $0$.

These are:

$0,1,7,8,11,12,18$